# typescript resolve files list

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

is it possible to emit the TSC resolved files list?

typescript compiler will resolve the files by /// 
and sort those files in order i want to emit the sorted files list into a file,
is it possible

in my case, i have folder structure like below

```
app/
    core/
        Math.ts
        Helpers.ts
    text/
        BarText.ts
        FooText.ts
```

I do not want to compile all of ts into own file nor all into single bundle.

"core" into app.core.js, "text" to app.text.js.
I use gulp to merge all the files as state above, but without knowing the file's order, it will have an issue when some class extends the other
like BarText actually extends FooText, but BarText will appear before in merged js file and cause error.

is there any way to achieve this?

sorry for my poor english, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this with TypeScript.  When using internal modules (aka namespaces in TS 1.5), correct ordering of files is the responsibility of the developer.

If you use external modules, then the dependencies of each file on other files is explicitly documented in the code and build tools should be able to automatically resolve the correct order (or it will be moot).